# How to fetch data from multi-line text field with append changes to existing text enabled in SharePoint online?

Tags: typescript, sharepoint-online, spfx

How do I retrieve values of a multi-line text field with append changes in spfx?
I tried to fetch the column data using a REST call but only the most recent text is being pulled.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this approach - you have to load all versions for the column - append multi line text is stored in old versions:

```js
const itemRet: any[] = await sp.web.lists.getById(listId).items.getById(itemId).versions
.select(FieldInternalName, 'Created', 'Editor')
.filter(FieldInternalName + ' ne null')
.get();
if (itemRet) {
  if (itemRet.length > 0) {
    columnData = [...itemRet];
  } else {
    columnData = []; // no history
  }
} else {
  columnData = [];
}
```